# How can I draw the following diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I have tried different things but nothing is really working. [image]

Here is my code so far.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pdftexcmds}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
    \mycirc/.style={circle,fill=blue!20, minimum size=0.5cm}

\coordinate [label={below right:(1.plads \, 2.plads \, 3.plads)}] (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate [label={above right:$5$ bolde}] (B) at (0, 3);
\coordinate [label={below left:$\mymk{1,2,3,4,5}$ bolde}] (C) at (-5, 0);

\node[mycirc,label=left:{$x$}] (n1) at (0,0) {};
%  \draw[color=red, ultra thick,-latex] (A) --> (B);
  \draw [very thick,-latex] (-4,0) -- (0,0);
  % \draw [very thick,-latex] (0,4) -- (-3,0);
    %  \draw [very thick,-latex] (0,3) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you show what have you tried?

Comment: Tried some commutative diagram. But the problem was I could not write text. Then just trying to draw some coordinate and draw arrows but again the problem is how to write text and how to draw ellipse and train of square.

Comment: Welcome. We know that if you ask a question, it's because you didn't know how to do it. What is important here is to give the code of your tests as the starting point for the answers.

Comment: Please add a full compileable code

Comment: you don't need tkz-euclide to get this diagram !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following draws and positions everything manually, but looks somewhat like your diagram.

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
    (0,0)
      node[draw, ellipse, text width=2cm, text centered](n) {A \\ $n$ elementer}
    (-6,-2)
      node[draw, ellipse, text width=2cm, text centered] (r) {$r$ elementer}
    ;
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,xshift=-2.5cm]
    \draw[dashed]
      (0,0) coordinate(dt1) -- ++(5,0) coordinate(dt2) --
      ++(0,.7) coordinate(dt3) -- (dt1|-dt3) -- cycle
      ;
    \foreach\x in {1,...,4}
      \draw[dashed] (dt1) ++(\x,0) -- ++(0,.7);
    \node at (3.5,.35) {\ldots};
    \foreach[count=\n]\x in {0,1,2}
      \node (tt\n) at (\x+0.5,1) {\n. pl};
    \node at (4.5,1) {$r$'te pl};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[->,>=stealth]
    (n) --node[above left]{Valg $1$}node[below right]{$x$} (r)
    ;
  \draw[->,>=stealth]
    (r) --node[above right]{$r!$}node[below left]{Valg $2$} (-2.5,-3.65);
  \draw[->,>=stealth]
    (n) --node[right]{$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ udfyldninger} (tt3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]